# How to get single value of an array if array is used as value corresponding to a key in HashMap?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

In the following code I'm using a String array as a `HashMap` value corresponding to a single key. The `get()` method of `HashMap` is returning the whole array. What if I want single value 
of array. (Say) I want only 'Lion' corresponding to key 'Animal'.

```
class HMTest{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     HashMap<String, String[]> subjects = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
     subjects.put("Fruit",new String[] {"mango","orange"});
     subjects.put("Animal",new String[] {"Lion","Tiger"});

     for(String s:subjects.get("Animal"))
       System.out.println(s);
     }
  }
```

I also tried replacing above for loop something like this

```
for(String[] s:subjects.get("Animal"))
       System.out.println(s[0]);
```

But its giving me error.

Anybody please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

Should be:

```
System.out.println(subjects.get("Animal")[0]);
```

The *value* of the `"Animal"` *key* is **an array**, not a String. Therefore, when you `get("Animal")`, you expect the value to be an array. Then you want to get the first element.

Comment: The `for` is not at all required.

Comment: Thats what I also tried in for loop, but its giving me error saying incompatible type.

Comment: @Winn Well.. don't use it in loop. Just wrote what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `for`. The `get()` fetches a single value.

```
String[] s = subjects.get("Animal");
System.out.println(s[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to use the following code:

```
  for(String[] s:subjects.get("Animal"))
     System.out.println(s[0]);
```

If it is working, then **`subjects.get("Animal")`** should be a type of `String[][]`. BUt in your code, it is a type of `String[]`. They are not matching..

Use  `System.out.println(subjects.get("Animal")[0]);` to print the first element in array.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of HashMap is a String array, just give the index of your desired value. Say, you want to see "Lion". Since its index is 0 at Animal array, you can say

```
System.out.println(subjects.get("Animal")[0]);
```

Output:

```
Lion
```